# Yammer REST API with O365 Yammer Resource Authentication

Tags: angular, yammer

I am trying to integrate Yammer REST API services in Angular 2 project.

1) Getting Yammer Authentication Token using https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2 because in my application am using Graph and SharePoint services.

2) Now, using that Yammer token & AJAX call trying to fetch topic feeds
`www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/about_topic/:topic_id.json` even I have tried **api.yammer.com** instead of **www.yammer.com** but it's throwing a Pre-Flight error.

3) But, for time being I am using WebRequest in C# and using C# functions as services to fetch feeds from Yammer.

How to fix this issue? I should call as CORS service.

**Note:** I don't want to do two login process for my app. Already authenticating the user using login.microsoft.com.

Comment: Ever find a solution for this?